@CascadeType.MERGE won't work on child entity
I am trying to implement a @ManyToMany relationship between 2 entities: user and authority. Supposing we have userA with authorities READ and WRITE and userB with authority READ, I want to be able to save both users and their authorities without having the READ authority saved twice in the authority table.
These are my tables:
CREATE TABLE user (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
);


CREATE TABLE authority (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    authority VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_authority (
    user_id BIGINT,
    authority_id BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, authority_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (authority_id) REFERENCES authority(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

And this is my code:

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "user", schema = "user_database")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id")
    )
    private Set<AuthorityEntity> authority;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "authority", schema = "user_database")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthorityEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String authority;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authority")
    private Set<UserEntity> users;
}

SERVICE:
    public Response<String> createUser(UserEntity user) {
        UserEntity saveUserEntity = userRepository.save(userEntity);
        log.info(saveUserEntity.toString());
        return new Response<>(200, "SUCCESS", saveUserEntity.toString());
    }

REPOSITORY:
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    UserEntity findByUsername(String username);
}

The desired output after saving both users is:
USER table
d, username, password

1,  userA,    1234

2,   userB,    4321

AUTHORITY table
id, authority

1,   READ

2,   WRITE

USER_AUTHORITY table
user_id, authority_id

1,        1

1,        2

2,        1

From past experience but also after doing some research I found out that my problem is related to the CascadeType variable inside the @ManyToMany annotation. Even though MERGE is the most suggested solution for the problem I'm having it doesn't seem to work. I tried various ways of using CascadeType but I have the following outputs:

CascadeType.ALL - after saving userA, when I try saving userB I get following error:


Duplicate entry 'READ' for key 'authority....


CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.ALL - same result as I got at point 1.

CascadeType.MERGE - after saving userA, when I try saving userB I get following error:



org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.AuthService.repository.entity.AuthorityEntity

I have also been trying with PERSIST in different variations. Still no luck.

Do both READ authorities point to the same object? Did you try saving the authorities before the users?

Probably the authorityEntity contained in the user entity is newly created and its id is null. Then it gets inserted. You should instead select the authorities by name and assign the list to the user entity before save.

You need to share the same Read Authority instance in the two object graphs, or you'll get two separate inserts for the 'same' authority value. You might have just used the authority  value as the identifier as it is the natural primary key that uniquely identifies these objects - and what you really want to use to distinguish identity and existence for these objects apparently. It muddles the FKs a bit though, so if you can't do that you'll have to understand that the only thing JPA users to distinguish the objects apart is the values in the entity you've marked as the ID.

The Duplicate entry 'READ' for key 'authority.... error occurs because you are trying to save two different AuthorityEntity objects with the same READ value in the authority field while you have declared this field as unique: authority VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL. Your userA and userB contain different AuthorityEntity instances because you have not specified ids for them. If you remove the unique constraint on the authority field, the save will succeed, but you will get content like this:
AUTHORITY

id, authority

1,   READ

2,   WRITE

3,   READ


USER_AUTHORITY

user_id, authority_id

1,        1

1,        2

2,        3

To get the content you want, you must first create the authority entities you want, and then when creating a user entity, select the existing authority entities for it.
The TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance... error when you remove CascadeType.ALL and leave only CascadeType.MERGE occurs because your AuthorityEntity objects do not have identifiers. Therefore, Hibernate considers them new entities that need to be persisted in the database, but you only allowed cascade merging by specifying CascadeType.MERGE, and for persist you need to use CascadeType.PERSIST.

Hello, Andrey. Thank you for the elaborate answer. You see, my intention is to be able to create new authorities by saving users that contain them. When I send to my microservice a request containing an User object that contains a list of authorities, I want them to be merged to the old ones, or to be created in case they don't exist in the db already, but without needing to also specify the authorities ID in order for the authority entity to be fully developed.

@SebastianMocanu If you want to merge new objects with old ones, you need to tell Hibernate which objects you consider new and which ones are old. Currently, Hibernate considers an object to have an ID as an old object, and if it doesn't have an ID, it's a new object.

And even if it has an ID, it will query the DB to decide if it is new or not.
